# Dockerize a windows GUI application

Tags: docker

Is it possible to run a Windows GUI executable (notepad.exe for example) into a container ?

I want to do this because i do not trust some software i install on my personal computer and i want to be sure they are runned into a sandbox

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd have to say that I don't think it's possible and if you understood windows containers you really wouldn't want to do it anyway. Last time I checked, a windows container weighs in at gigabytes++ and that's huge to run notepad.

You can run xwindows apps in a container, but windows is, basically, complete shite in a container.

If you want a sandbox then you should checkout [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or [Hyper-V](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/). You can script either with [Hashicorp Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/).